# Convert an image into color coded grid

Tags: drawing, grids, pixel-grid

Is there any software or an online site which could convert an image into a grid of given size and each box in the grid will have a color code (easiest if just black and white) so that filling the grid could give us the picture? It'll work like pixels but of course the grid size could vary and could effect the image quality. Is there anything that could do that?

Each box in the grid could be numbered and a map of number-to-color could be provided.

Edit: There are softwares which convert images into a paint-by-number image but it's not a grid. Basically I just want that software
to reduce the pixel density to a given value and color code the final grid with a given color scheme.

Comment: This is precisely what pixel art is. There are a lot of tools to create pixel art if you search for them.

Comment: It sounds to me like a bitmap with a defined palete.

Comment: @Rafael, yes but a script is needed to place a number on each pixel/square and create a map of the used colors. Probably best make a vector SVG. For me it would be easiest to make with JavaScript in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring halftones and pixel filters, probably the closest thing to this is what used to be called "ascii" art, but is now generally referred to as "textmode."

Most of these software programs allow you to use your own fonts and character sets, so it is trivial to set up a fixed-width font with e.g. 16 glyphs that each correspond to a color.

Chuck Close did this either via mechanical means, manual coding, and/or a hybrid of both.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, you can configure a conversion of an image with e.g. a fixed-width font set at 80 columns, 80 rows: a very manageable grid.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you need.

1. A bitmap or raster image is a grid of a given size.
2. Each box, a pixel can have a color code when is on indexed mode. You assign one of 256 colors, and then you can change the value of the palette affecting each pixel of that indexed pallete.
3. You can change the dimensions of the bitmap, having then a different sized grid.

---

What is not clear is where you need to apply this resulting grid.

As described you could even use a worksheet with conditional formatting and form an image based on the number of each cell, or perhaps you can make an Html table with a different class with a number, and then prepare a stylesheet to assign the colors to each class.

The missing part is converting an image to this table. Probably you can use some format like PNG*, consult the documentation, and open it in a hex editor to extract some values from the image file, and then transport it into your desired application.

- I have no idea which format you can edit and extract the values. Probably an uncompressed one like BMP.